# ¿Por que relanzar una excepción dentro del bloque catch?

Tags: c#, .net, excepciones, try-catch

En este articulo https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/ aparece la frase en ingles:

> "Do not catch an exception unless you can handle it and leave the
>   application in a known state. If you catch System.Exception, rethrow
>   it using the throw keyword at the end of the catch block."

*(No atrape una excepción a menos que pueda manejarla y dejar la aplicación en un estado conocido. Si lo atrapa System.Exception, vuelva a lanzarlo usando la throwpalabra clave al final del catchbloque.)*

Y en este otro articulo aparece este ejemplo donde se lanza una excepcion con el bloque catch:

```
using System;

 public class Sentence
 {
  public Sentence(string s)
  {
   Value = s;
  }

 public string Value { get; set; }

   public char GetFirstCharacter()
   {
     try {
       return Value[0];
         }
     catch (NullReferenceException e) {
       throw;   
         } 
      }
     }

         public class Example 
    {
   public static void Main()
   {
    var s = new Sentence(null);
    Console.WriteLine($"The first character is 
   {s.GetFirstCharacter()}");
   }
  }
// The example displays the following output:
//    Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object 
     reference not set to an instance of an object.
//       at Sentence.GetFirstCharacter()
//       at Example.Main()
```

No entiendo para que hay que hacerlo si daña el stack trace y ya se esta atrapando la excepción en el bloque catch.
¿Qué pasa si **no** uso "**throw**" dentro del bloque catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes capturar la excepción original y no hacer un throw de ella o de una distinta. Eso es porque es una excepción "controlada" y que sabes cómo tratarla, que esa lógica es la que implementas en el catch de la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión está mal hacer eso. El `throw` vuelve a lanzar la misma excepción que se ha capturado en el `catch`, sin añadir nada útil. Todo el bloque catch sobra en ese caso. Como bien indicas, el único efecto conseguido es perjudicial: se daña el stack trace. Si dentro del bloque `try` hubiera varias líneas donde se pudiera generar la excepción, se perdería la información del número de línea original que produjo la excepción.

Ahora bien: el artículo citado dice otra cosa: si se captura en un bloque catch una excepción genérica (`System.Exception`), se puede volver a lanzar la misma excepción **al final** del bloque catch después de haber hecho buen uso de la excepción capturada, por ejemplo grabando un log, o cualquier cosa que sea necesaria como consecuencia de la excepción. Pero un bloque catch que únicamente tenga un `throw` es una insensatez.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo, no tiene sentido la siguiente expresión

```
try
{
 //--you code here---
}
catch(Exception)
{throw;}
```

Pero a lo mejor tienes un bloque de código cuya excepción quieres guardar en un log cuando ocurra en él un problema, pero además quieres detener el proceso y tratar el error a un nivel más alto. Entonces tiene perfecto sentido...

```
try
{
//you code here---
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Error(ex);
throw;
}
```